# Drag mutiple buttons at a time on touch event in Android?

Tags: android

in Application i want to create multiple buttons and apply events for them   simultaneously.?
I have create dynamic button with follwing code  but when i apply touch event on two buuton  then event is apply only 1 button a t a time

I have created mutiple button iwth below code..

```
for(int ii= 0;ii <6;ii++)
            { 



params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             params.width = 50;
             params.height = 50;


                switch(ii)
                 {
                 case 0:
                     params.setMargins(100,200, 0, 0);
                 break; 
                 case 1:
                     params.setMargins(350,200, 0, 0);
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     params.setMargins(600,200, 0, 0);
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     params.setMargins(300,400, 0, 0);
                     break;
                 case 4:
                     params.setMargins(100,500, 0, 0);
                     break;
                 case 5:
                     params.setMargins(350,500, 0, 0);
                     break;

                 }


        }



@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
             switch (eventaction) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  

                 System.out.println("************event.getAction()******"+event.getRawX()+"*********"+event.getRawY());
                 params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 params.setMargins((int)(event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2))-25, (int)(event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()/2))-25,0,0);
                 params.width =100;
                 params.height=100;
                 v.setLayoutParams(params);
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Staticmethodclass.changecurrentplay = "Yes";

                   if(event.getRawX() < 780 && event.getRawY() < 1200 && event.getRawX()>=0 && event.getRawY()>=0)
                 {
                    params =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins((int)(event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int)(event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()/2)),0,0);
                    params.width =100;
                    params.height=100;
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                 }

             break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 System.out.println("*****actionup****event.getAction()******"+event.getRawX()+"*********"+event.getRawY());
                 if(event.getRawX() < 780 && event.getRawY() < 1200 && event.getRawX()>=0 && event.getRawY()>=0)
                 {
                 params =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//               params=(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                 params.setMargins((int)(event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2))+25, (int)(event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()/2))+25,0,0);
                 params.width = 50;
                 params.height= 50;
                 v.setLayoutParams(params);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.println("***else***event.getAction()******"+event.getRawX()+"*********"+event.getRawY());
                     android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params1 =(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                     params1.setMargins((int)params1.leftMargin+25, (int)(params1.topMargin+25),0,0);
                     params1.width = 50;
                     params1.height= 50;
                     v.setLayoutParams(params1);
                 }

             return false;
```

plz help..?

Comment: Instead of [duplicating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171516/how-to-move-multiple-buttons-on-touch-in-android) questions, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10172576/edit) them.

Answer (score 0):

if you touch any button it will simply make that button as a View v, for effecting other buttons you should no go for like that, instead of single button, place all buttons inside a layout and then move them on touch view so, ultimately it will move all dynamic buttons you defined dynamically inside a layout and it will move the layout instead of a single button, so you can move more than one buttons placing them inside a layout and move that layout.

Comment: means move the frame layout,cos it contains buttons so if you can move the whole frame layout then all button will move, when you initalize a button dynamically, add it to frame layout and move the frame layout instead of button. i.e. dont implement touch listener on button instead, implement on frame layout.

Comment: I will not move all buttons at a time only those button in which only touch action is performed means those buttons in which it may be 1 button or more than 1 button simultaneously.